# Some Issue with running "WEbrick"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, webrick

After I installed ruby 1.9.2p290(with rubyInstaller) on windows 7 and
connected MySQL to it ( I checked it
and it worked ) I installed rails then I create a project on

"C:\Users\Amiref\Documents\Sites\simple_cms"

with this order : "rails new simple_cms -d mysql"
then when I use "rails server" to run webrick I saw this error on
command prompt :

```
"rails.bat :
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in
`require': Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compile
d for 6.0.0 but the client library is 5.1.45. (RuntimeError)
At line:1 char:6
+ rails <<<<  server
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:/Ruby192/lib/...
(RuntimeError):String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

from
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in
`<top (required)>'
from
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in
`require'
from
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in
`<top (required)>'
from
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in
`require'
from
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in
`block (2 levels) in require'
from
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in
`each'
from
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in
`block in require'
from
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in
`each'
from
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in
`require'
from
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in
`require'
from
C:/Users/Amiref/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in
`<top (required)>'
from
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in
`require'
 from
 C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in
`block in <top (required)>'
 from
 C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in
 `tap'
from
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in
`<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
"
```

Comment: "Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 6.0.0 but the client library is 5.1.45."

Comment: If i know, how I can solve this prblem , I never ask it . now If you know how I can solve it then help me.

Comment: Install an updated version of MySQL? Install an older version of the gem?

Comment: I went to mysql site and installed the latest version that is available on the site and it was mysql 5.5 but now I don't understand why rails give such a message. If I remove 1)ruby 2)ruby on rails 3)mysql 5.5 and reinstall them , Can I hope to solve that error?

Answer (score 12):

The newest rails or ruby use mysql-connector-c-6 (libmysql.dll) compile mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32, so you should use the 6 client dll.

There is a easy way to let RailsInstaller(Ruby1.9.2)  use mysql-connector-c-6:

1. download mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip
2. Unzip the mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip and copu mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32\lib\libmysql.dll to RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\bin

Then run rails server and everything is OK.

Comment: You can download the mysql connector from the following link: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Comment: When you gem install mysql2, it displays a helpful message telling you this and even gives you the above link to the correct version of libmysql.dll. However, if you install the gem with bundler, bundler eats the message!

Answer (score 2):

Read the error message. Your `MySQL` gem expects version `6.0.0`, but you have `5.1.45` installed.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused because a gem (probably either mysql or mysql2) was used in your project and the binaries of that gem were compiled against a different version of MySQL than the one you have installed.

Both mysql and mysql2 gems depends on you having `libmysql.dll` library in the PATH, which could differ from the one used to build those gems.

Most likely you used Bundler to install those gems, which chewed the installation notes about where to get that particular version of `libmysql.dll`

I would recommend you remove the installed mysql, mysql2 gems along the `libmysql.dll` you have somewhere in your PATH and follow the instructions described here:

http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

You can skip the installation of MySQL itself, but pay attention to the usage of MySQL Connector/C binaries (zip archive, not the installer) and how to install it.

Once you've completed the installation of either mysql or mysql2 gem (the install instructions work for both), please update your bundle:

```
bundle check
```

So it reflects the local installed version.

Hope that helps.